# xpath not returning data i need from website

Tags: xpath

https://www.reviewcentre.com/car_dealers/we_buy_any_car_-_wwwwebuyanycarcom-review_14068020

here this website, i am struggling badly to return the actual car review data

i have tried

```
//h:[@id="ReviewRating-14068020"]
```

and

```
//h:div[@class='reviewBody']
```

is there something stupid I am doing. I have spent hours and hours trying to figure this out. Thanks in advance for any advice you can bring.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you add this `h:` to XPath but you should not do this

To get review text try:

```
//span[@property="reviewBody"]/text()
```

To get rating:

```
//div[@property="reviewRating"]/text()
```

Comment: hi, i added the h: because of the application am using, which is rapidminer, but thanks, hopefully this might help with my understanding